# How could I reword this sentence to exclude I?

Tags: american-english, pronouns

---

I am writing a report for choir, and I will get docked points if I use the word "I" or "you." So, I need assistance in figuring out how to reword this sentence to get rid of the I, but in a way that will still make sense... "The musical performance that I attended was..."

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Thank you all so much! This helped a lot, and I think that I will get a better score on my report now! Thanks again!! :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [writing advice is off-topic according to our Help Center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply remove the I!

> “The musical performance was...”

Based on the context you’ve provided, that you’re writing some sort of report or review about a performance, it’s already assumed that you were present. You’re writing to talk about the performance so just focus on that. If you’ve got additional context (what comes after that sentence?) then I’m happy to help you work with that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove it. The style you are looking for is called Third Person.

> "The musical performance was an exciting event that was enjoyed by the
>   entire audience."

To further assist you as you continue writing, avoid thinking about the event as you experienced it - instead imagine you are a camera objectively recording events.

Here is a good intro/guide on writing in third-person, but I encourage further research into similar resources to help develop the style more.

https://www.aresearchguide.com/write-in-third-person.html